# BeautifulSoup-Python : How do you scrape data that has not been loaded yet?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried scraping using BeautifulSoup but it returns `[]`. Then when I tried viewing the source code there's div `class="loading32"`.

How do you scrape this kind of elements ?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = productUrl  # bs4 part
uClient = uReq(my_url)  # bs4 part
page_html = uClient.read()  # bs4 part
uClient.close()  # bs4 part
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")  # bs4 part
description = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ui-box product-description-main"})
string4 = str(description)
```

URL : https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/100-Original-16-Shimano-Casitas-150-151-150hg-151hg-Right-Left-Hand-Baitcasting-Fishing-Reel-4/1053031_32657797704.html?spm=2114.12010608.0.0.22e12d66I7a3Dp

```
<div class="ui-box product-description-main" id="j-product-description">
        <div class="ui-box-title">Product Description</div>
        <div class="ui-box-body">

            <div class="description-content" data-role="description" data-spm="1000023">
            <div class="loading32"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you have tried so far. What are you trying to extract with it?

Comment: How are you fetching the html source?  That page likely has dynamic javascript that alters the html content after it's loaded.  If you're fetching the html directly from the server with something like `requests` or `urlopen`, then the javascript never executes.

Comment: @MartinEvans question has been edited and I'm scraping via BeautifulSoup

Comment: @JohnGordon yes, I'm using requests & urlopen, just started learning bs4. Are there any other options ?

Comment: But what are you trying to get? Various product details, the image?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to get those details because their API didn't provide it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information is all there, it does not need javascript to be used. You just need to look through the HTML that is returned and decide the best method to extract each item that you want. I have guessed you might be trying to get something like the following:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

my_url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/100-Original-16-Shimano-Casitas-150-151-150hg-151hg-Right-Left-Hand-Baitcasting-Fishing-Reel-4/1053031_32657797704.html?spm=2114.12010608.0.0.22e12d66I7a3Dp'
uClient = uReq(my_url)  # bs4 part
page_html = uClient.read()  # bs4 part
uClient.close()  # bs4 part

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")  # bs4 part

details = {}
details['Product Name'] = soup.find('h1', class_='product-name').text
details['Price Range'] = soup.find('div', class_='p-current-price').find_all('span')[1].text

item_specifics = soup.find('ul', class_='product-property-list util-clearfix')
for li in item_specifics.find_all('li'):
    entry = li.get_text(strip=True).split(':')
    details[entry[0]] = ', '.join(entry[1:])

# Locate the image    
li = soup.find('div', class_='ui-image-viewer-thumb-wrap')
url = li.img['src']
details['Image URL'] = url
details['Image Filename'] = url.rsplit('/', 1)[1]

for item, desc in details.items():
    print('{:30} {}'.format(item, desc))
```

Would give you the following information:

```
Product Name                   Original 2016 Shimano Casitas 150 151 150hg 151hg Right Left Hand Baitcasting Fishing Reel 4+1BB 5.5kg SVS Infinity fishing reel
Price Range                    83.60 - 85.60
Fishing Method                 Bait Casting
Baits Type                     Fake Bait
Position                       Ocean Rock Fshing,River,Stream,Reservoir Pond,Ocean Beach Fishing,Lake,Ocean Boat Fishing
Fishing Reels Type             Baitcast Reel
Model Number                   Casitas
Brand Name                     Shimano
Ball Bearings                  4+1BB
Feature 1                      Shimano Stable Spool S3D
Feature 2                      SVS Infinity Brake System (Infinite Cast Control)
Model                          150/ 151/ 150HG/ 151HG
PE Line (50 test /m)           20-150/30-135/ 40-105
Nylon Line (51hg test /m)      10-120/12-110/14-90
Weight                         190g
Gear Ratio                     6.3, 1 / 7.2, 1
Made in                        Malaysia
Image URL                      https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1qRKzJFXXXXboXVXXq6xXFXXXU/Original-2016-Shimano-Casitas-150-151-150hg-151hg-Right-Left-Hand-Baitcasting-Fishing-Reel-4-1BB.jpg_640x640.jpg
Image Filename                 Original-2016-Shimano-Casitas-150-151-150hg-151hg-Right-Left-Hand-Baitcasting-Fishing-Reel-4-1BB.jpg_640x640.jpg
```

The image information is also stored. This could then be downloaded using another `uReq` call and saving the data as binary into a file using the filename obtained.

Comment: How about those pictures below it ?

Comment: They would need to be downloaded as another request and saved as binary data. I have shown a possible way to get the image details.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem here is, these `loading32` elements are being loaded via compiled `javascript` on the client end. This is an ideal use case for `Splash`. `ScrapingHub` has this `renderer` that can be used via `curl API` and you can execute some `Lua` code also that can help you circumvent a lot of problems like js triggered page loads, waits, clicks and whatnot.

Link : [Splash Documentation](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Also, you can integrate this `Splash` with `Scrapy`, amazing right.

Link : [Scrapy Splash Github](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)

Comment: sounds to complicated. is there any way using bs4 ?

Comment: No.  You need to fetch the code using a browser, or something like a browser, so the javascript code has a chance to execute.  Then you can parse the result with bs4.

Comment: @JackAQ the JS needs to be executed, hence, the solution. I guess that's the only way to circumvent around this issue. If it helps, do tell